# First Steps of Making a Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create my own programming language and a compiler for it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-create-my-own-programming-language-and-a-compiler-for-it)

*Note: This is not a possible duplicate; it is more specified.*

What is the first step into making your own programming language? Is it something you jump into, or are there steps you must take? Thanks!