# Are there any podcasts (not lectures) about compiler development?

Tags: compiler

There are several podcasts with lectures from universities. I am looking for "other" podcasts.

So are there any non-lecture podcasts about compiler development?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Below are podcasts on compiler development from [Software Engineering Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/):

- [Episode 61 Internals of GCC](http://www.se-radio.net/2007/07/episode-61-internals-of-gcc/)
- [Episode 182 Domain Specific
  Languages](http://www.se-radio.net/2012/01/episode-182-domain-specific-languages-with-martin-fowler-and-rebecca-parsons/)
- [Episode 160 Aspect J and Spring AOP](http://www.se-radio.net/2010/04/episode-160-aspectj-and-spring-aop-with-ramnivas-laddad/)
- [Episode 118 Eelco Visser on Parsers](http://www.se-radio.net/2008/11/episode-118-eelco-visser-on-parsers/)
- [Episode 57 Compile time Meta Programming](http://www.se-radio.net/2007/05/episode-57-compile-time-metaprogramming/)
- [Episode 44 Interview with Brian Goetz and David Holmes](http://www.se-radio.net/2007/01/episode-44-interview-brian-goetz-and-david-holmes/)
- [Episode 36 Interview with Guy Steele](http://www.se-radio.net/2006/11/episode-36-interview-guy-steele/)

Oresoft Live Web Class:

- [Compiler Design](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDAE55AEE0731D729&feature=plcp) (42 videos)

Blip.tv

- [Introduction to Compilers](http://blip.tv/g400-by-marcus-whybrow/g52cmp-01-introduction-3172019)

Google Tech Talks:

- [LLVM](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1921156852099786640)
- [Learning to Analyze Sequences](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIcpAFHSdbM)
- [Code Generation with Ruby](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv7J50IeBLs)
- [Compiling Dynamic Languages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKFeLZqLxzQ&feature=plcp&context=C30f1131UDOEgsToPDskKfCFu92oTGKcjQ5Gy7n-1d)
- [GCC: Current Topics and Future Directions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfwNbUxbKr0)
- [Compiling and Optimizing Scripting Languages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKySEUrP7LA)
- [Building Industrial Strength Performance Tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXYoP0P2Xk&feature=plcp&context=C3fd37c7UDOEgsToPDskJ3JAlpvCwOeGar-OeFVoeD)
- [DMS: Software Tool Infrastructure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-_dw9iEzhA&feature=plcp&context=C3949f38UDOEgsToPDskJU_bY9ZS-tbTf5NeVLdHFE)
- [Tools for Continuous Integration at Google Scale](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b52aXZ2yi08&feature=plcp&context=C3ee637fUDOEgsToPDskKxY7SQ6bu1U6jg-p7l2QUi)
- [Cross Compiling Android Applications to iPhone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG-NIt2O5J8&feature=plcp&context=C3161a35UDOEgsToPDskI1cra7NwiFP28cwROiFlBP)

YouTube:

- [How the Compiler Works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dan4hJlOv0&feature=autoplay&list=PL8656356E99E5C01D&lf=results_main&playnext=1)
- [Lexical Analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-nkdR4H530&feature=bf_next&list=PL8656356E99E5C01D&lf=results_main)
- [Syntax Analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KL7A5c0O0Yk&feature=bf_next&list=PL8656356E99E5C01D&lf=results_main)
- [Code Generation and Optimization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88bnJE-UP6M&feature=bf_prev&list=PL8656356E99E5C01D&lf=results_main&index=1)
- [Code Generation of the JVM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA1wwBbFMcU)
- [Lexical Scanning in Go](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE)

Channel 9:

- [Eric Lippert - On Compiler Evolution, Designing C# and Blogging](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Checking-In-with-Erik-Meijer/Checking-In-Eric-Lippert-On-Compiler-Evolution-Designing-C-and-Blogging)

Confreaks:

- [Towards a Ruby Compiler](http://confreaks.net/videos/175-rubyconf2009-towards-a-ruby-compiler)
- [How to Implement your own Programming Language](http://confreaks.net/videos/645-gogaruco2011-smalltalk-on-rubinius-or-how-to-implement-your-own-programming-language)

TWIT Network's [Floss Weekly](http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly) discussed related topics:

- [Guido van Rossum (language design)](http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/11)
- [PHP Creator Rasmus Lerdorf (origins of PHP)](http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/12)
- [Superfeedr](http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/186)

Computer Science [Podcast](http://computersciencepodcast.com/index.html) has:

- [May 2011 Compilers Everywhere](http://computersciencepodcast.com/podcasts.html)

Comment: I am overwhelmed by this answer. The power of SE, right here.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen Is there a particular reason why you are not interested in online lectures related to Compiler construction? The reason why I asked is because [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) is about to offer an excellent free course on [Compilers](https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers). Everyone interested in compilers should **not** miss this.

Comment: Simply because I knew about (a lot) of them already.